# Oracle SYSTPH* Type

Tags: oracle, types, oracle11g, toad

We've noticed in the TOAD schema browser some weird types which seem to pop up randomly throughout the day on our database.  We found them by using the Schema Browser in TOAD under Types -> Collection Types.  They have names like these:

```
SYSTPHYP5bsxIC47gU0Z4MApeAw==
SYSTPHYP8cBHQYUDgU0Z4MApvyA==
SYSTPHYPwYo541RfgU0Z4MAqeTQ==
```

They seem to have randomly generated names and we're pretty sure our application is not creating them.  They are all `TABLE OF NUMBER(20)`

Does anyone have an explanation of what these types are for?

Answer (score 2):

These are most likely related to use of the collect aggregate function.  You can find some info here on them:

http://orasql.org/2012/04/28/a-funny-fact-about-collect/

Looks like in the past there was a bug (Bug 4033868 fixed in 11g) where these types did not clean up after themselves.

Comment: Our application is small enough that I'm able to verify none of the uses of collect involve a type of "TABLE OF NUMBER(20)".  This was a good read though. I give you an upvote.